# Understanding Bounded Waiting

Tags: operating-systems

I am trying to understand bounded waiting and i have a question.

The definition is as follows:

Bounded waiting - 
There exists a bound, or limit, on the number of times
that other processes are allowed to enter their critical sections after a
process has **made a request to enter its critical section** and before that
request is granted.

Does this mean after process 2 has made a request to enter its own critical section or the critical section of process 1?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33409854/5785085)

Comment: Each process has its own critical section that only it enters.